# R error with using cbind() on a data.frame() in a for loop

Tags: r

```
d <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=F)

for (i in 1:ncol(data)) { d <- cbind(d,data[,i])}

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 132680
```

Why I am getting the error above?

Answer (score 3):

Probably for the precise reason R told you it went wrong: the two items you are trying to `cbind` together have different numbers of rows.

Your data frame `d` is emtpy, and so has 0 rows. Apparently your data frame `data` (which you've provided us zero information on, by the way) has 132680 rows.

There's probably a better way to do what you're attempting (`cbind`ing columns in a for loop is often not terribly optimal), but it's difficult to propose a solution without more details.

Comment: s/often not terribly optimal/often a terrible idea

Comment: My  idea was to extract and re-combine the columns of an existing dataframe for a specific purpose.Eg: I find the columns of the data.frame() that is the result of an import from a read.csv() statement, sometimes have Date columns read in as a Character class. Another reason is that, I just need only a few columns from a data.frame() created from a read.csv statement. I did not realize that the data.frame() I initialized before the for loop would need to filled with a column vector with row length equal to that of any objects parsed to cbind() later

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to hack a solution along the lines of what you have above, but you probably don't want to.  What is your goal here?

```
d <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=0,nrow=5),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
set.seed(101)
dat <- matrix(sample(LETTERS,replace=TRUE,size=10),ncol=2)
for (i in 1:ncol(dat)) { d <- cbind(d,dat[,i])}
d2 <- as.data.frame(dat,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

In this particular example `dat` is a matrix of `character`; `d` is a data frame with two `factor` columns (**note** that `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` does **not** set an attribute of the data frame, so your later `cbind()` calls induce conversion to factor anyway!); and `d2` is perhaps (???) what you wanted, the original data set converted to a data frame ...

```
> str(dat)
 chr [1:5, 1:2] "J" "B" "S" "R" "G" "H" "P" "I" "Q" "O"
> str(d)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ dat[, i]: Factor w/ 5 levels "B","G","J","R",..: 3 1 5 4 2
 $ dat[, i]: Factor w/ 5 levels "H","I","O","P",..: 1 4 2 5 3
> str(d2)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ V1: chr  "J" "B" "S" "R" ...
 $ V2: chr  "H" "P" "I" "Q" ...
```